# warehouserevation Items to inventories as a linq query to run in foreach

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 lists which I need to update based on List input, The below code is working fine but how can i reduce to 1 for each

List warehouseReservationItems

List ExistingInvetories

```
List processedItems(input)
{
  "reservationId": 0,
  "warehouseId": 0,
  "itemList": [
    {
      "itemId": "string",
      "rejected": true,
      "binInventoryList": [
        {
          "binId": 0,
          "qtyFilled": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am looping the input and filtering the reservation item and again looping bin list from input and filtering the bin inventories list

```
foreach (var item in processedItems) //I am checking each item from input
{
    var modifiedItem = warehouseReservationItems?.FirstOrDefault(wri => wri.ItemId == item.ItemId); // filtering the item

    var inventoriesToUpdate = item.BinInventoryList.SelectMany(rib => existingInventories.Where(winv => winv.ItemId == modifiedItem.ItemId && rib.BinId == winv.BinId)).ToList();// filtering the inventories
    foreach (var modifiedInventory in inventoriesToUpdate)
    {
        var bin = item.BinInventoryList.FirstOrDefault(bin => bin.BinId == modifiedInventory.BinId);
        // Update the quantity reserved
        if (modifiedItem.QtyFilled <= modifiedItem.QtyOrdered)
        {
            if (modifiedItem.QtyFilled + bin.QtyFilled > modifiedItem.QtyOrdered)
            {
                modifiedInventory.QtyReserved = (modifiedInventory.QtyReserved - modifiedItem.QtyOrdered) + modifiedItem.QtyFilled;
            }
            else
            {
                modifiedInventory.QtyReserved -= bin.QtyFilled; // removing the quantity reserved
            }
        }
        // update the quantity on Hand
        if (bin.QtyFilled <= modifiedInventory.QtyOnHand)
        {
            modifiedItem.QtyFilled += bin.QtyFilled; // adding qtyfilled to item qtyalreadyFilled
            modifiedInventory.QtyOnHand -= bin.QtyFilled; // removing the QtyFilled from inventory qtyOnHand 
        }
        else
        {
            // throw error the qty filled has to be less than qtyon hand
            _errorDictionary.Add(modifiedInventory.ItemId + "(" + modifiedInventory.BinId.ToString() + ")", new[] { $" Quantity filled({bin.QtyFilled}) was more than the quantity On Hand ({modifiedInventory.QtyOnHand}) " });
        }
        updatedInventory.Add(modifiedInventory);
    }
    modifiedItem.SetReservationItemStatus(modifiedItem.QtyFilled, modifiedItem.QtyOrdered);

}
```

Comment: Your code does not appear to match your data. On line 3, you reference `item.ItemId` where `item` is an element of `processedItems`, but in your data, `ItemId` is deeper in the data structure - inside the `itemList` collection..

Comment: WarehousereservationItems has itemid and existing inventories has Itemid but the binid is unique here So I am filtering in line 3

Comment: Perhaps I was misinterpreting the posted data sample. When I see `foreach (var item in processedItems)` I was expecting the loop variable `item` to have properties `reservationId`, `warehouseId`, and `itemList`. Should the loop be `foreach (var item in processedItems.itemList)` maybe?

Comment: No. Processed items are command.ItemlIst